# How to react to "many people want/say/think" statements at work?

Tags: communication

I recently dealt with situations when a decision was being taken or a statement was being made, with the structure of
"we must do A, because many people want this"

or

"the way you work is not OK, many people say this"

When I ask for details, e.g. "who, in particular? any names?", the other person reacts with

1. it is what it is
2. silence
3. changing the topic
4. getting offended

or a combination of the above.
In a company, how to respond to "many people wants/say/think" statements?

Comment: Ask how they think you could do things differently. Ask what the interests of the many people are, which are being affected by the current patterns of behavior. Or just thank them for the feedback and move on.

Comment: I always make a joke that they must have a copy of the "Most People" book my mother-in-law used to have which told her exactly what most people did in all situations.  In this case it must be the companion volume, "Many People."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you haven't given much context here, your response seems very confrontational. Looking at this in two possible situations:

1. The person telling you this information is to some extent the authority in their domain (e.g. the product owner in your "we must do A, because many people want this" case or your manager in your "the way you work is not OK, many people say this" case) - by demanding names, you are saying that you do not trust their judgement, and will only act on the information if you are told it directly. To take the second case again, a much better response would be "I'm sorry to hear that. Could you give me some specific examples of things I have done wrong so I can learn from them?"
2. The person telling you this information is not an authority in their domain. In this case, it is certainly much more appropriate to question the validity of acting on the information - but there is still no need for a confrontational response. Try and find a way which shows you respect their judgement, but aren't going to act on it right away.

Comment: For case 1: wanting the source of information is not a problem and people should not be "offended" by that. I am not going to believe someone said something because another someone said the first someone said it, manager or not.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain: If my manager tells me that "many people" want me to do something, I am going to assume that my manager knows who those people are and cares about their opinions (because otherwise, why would they bring it up in the first place?). Since it's my manager's job to decide what I should be doing, I don't actually care who those "many people" are or why their opinions are important.